# Cover MsgPack to Object

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr

I am work with SignalR on Flutter FrameWork.

[link lib](https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_netcore)

When I setup with Msgpack, I receive value as following:

```
[433881865258414134, [433881865258414134, 1500521685979202, 01014045, Hoàng, Ngô Minh]]
```

The result I want is a Object

```
{
  'id': 433881865258414134,
  'item':{
     'id': 433881865258414134,
     'idReferent': 1500521685979202,
     'userID':01014045,
     'firsName':'Hoàng',
     'lastName': 'Ngô Minh'
  }
}
```

How to covert value from Msgpack to Object?